# SQL Server DATEDIFF round up the YEAR difference. How to round it down?

Tags: sql, sql-server, rounding, datediff

I have a problem that I tried googling but most questions are about rounding down hours or minutes.

I'm checking birthday dates for users and I have two dates that are 99.3 years apart. That means that the user is 99 years old but this piece of code:

```
DATEDIFF(YEAR, r.BirthDate, ISNULL(@Date,GETDATE()))
```

returns a value of 100. Is there a way to round the value down?

Comment: What RDBMS do you use?

Comment: @MaximFedorov  DATEDIFF and GETDATE() reside on MS SQL Server, thus I am concluding it is SQL Server

Comment: `DATEDIFF` counts *transitions*. Which is a perfectly valid approach but likely not what you're wanting to count to determine age.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this logic to get the correct age:

```
select (case when month(birthdate) * 100 + day(birthdate) >=
                  month(getdate()) * 100 + day(getdate())
             then year(getdate()) - year(birthdate)
             else year(getdate()) - year(birthdate) - 1
        end) as age
```

This should be accurate, even in the presence of leap years.  Basically it looks at the month-day portion of the birthdate and checks if it is on or later than today.  The logic uses this information to determine the age in year.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following solution using `MONTH` instead of `YEAR`:

```
DECLARE @currdate AS DATE = '2019-02-08'

-- using YEAR
SELECT DATEDIFF(YEAR, '2000-05-01', ISNULL(@currdate, GETDATE())) -- 19

-- using MONTH
SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH, '2000-05-01', ISNULL(@currdate, GETDATE())) / 12 -- 18
```

You can also `ROUND` up and down:

```
DECLARE @date DATE = '2019-02-08'

SELECT CAST(ROUND(DATEDIFF(MONTH, '1999-08-01', ISNULL(@date, GETDATE())) / 12.0, 0) AS INT) 
-- 20 (19.5)

SELECT CAST(ROUND(DATEDIFF(MONTH, '1999-09-01', ISNULL(@date, GETDATE())) / 12.0, 0) AS INT) 
-- 19 (19.4)
```

---

**is there a way to round down days?**

You can use days to round for days but this isn't more precise in some cases. You can check if the current date passed the day of birth or not ([as @Cato mentioned in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54591605/datediff-round-down-year-difference-to-lower-value/54591715#comment95980788_54591715)). In case the day of birth is greater than the current day (in same month) you can subtract a month.

```
DECLARE @birthday AS DATE = '2000-10-25'
DECLARE @currdate AS DATE = '2100-10-24'
SELECT ((DATEDIFF(MONTH, @birthday, ISNULL(@currdate, GETDATE())) - (CASE WHEN MONTH(@birthday) = MONTH(@currdate) AND DAY(@birthday) > DAY(@currdate) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) / 12)
-- 99
```

Comment: This works great with months, but is there a way to round down days? Because there is a possible scenario that it will show the user as 99 years old on 25th of october if the user's birthday is on 20th of october and will not show him as 100 years old until november starts.

Comment: don't go down this sort of route, there are always cases where (days old ) / 365.25 will not quite work.  Us the technique of finding the difference in years then finding out if the person had a birthday yet

Answer (score 2):

fin the difference in whole years (year - birth year) This is always the age the person reaches in that year.  Knock a year off if it is earlier than their birthday.

Never be tempted to use day difference divided by 365.25 or 365 - for all sorts of reasons, the age can end up coming out wrong at certain dates, sometimes around leap-years

```
SELECT YEAR(getdate()) - YEAR(birthdate)  
       - CASE WHEN MONTH(getdate()) < MONTH(birthdate) 
               OR (DAY(getdate()) < DAY(birthdate) AND MONTH(getdate()) = MONTH(birthdate) )
            THEN
                1
            ELSE
                0
            END
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how fixed it.

Instead of:

```
DATEDIFF(YEAR, r.BirthDate, ISNULL(@Date,GETDATE()))
```

use this:

```
FLOOR(DATEDIFF(week, r.BirthDate, ISNULL(@Date,GETDATE())) / 52.177457)
```

Here's [an article](https://vladmihalcea.com/sql-cross-apply/) that demonstrates that this trick works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted solution by Gordon is good but the logic is reversed?  The general idea is to see if the current month + day is greater than the birthdate's month + day and, if not, then subtract a year from the difference in years, because it hasn't reached or surpassed their birthdate yet.

```
SELECT YEAR(GETDATE()) - YEAR(birthdate) 
- IIF(MONTH(GETDATE()) * 100 + DAY(GETDATE()) >= MONTH(birthdate) * 100 + DAY(birthdate), 0, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this (without calculating the date difference 3 times or more) is to get the total number of years when subtracting the two values:

```
SELECT datediff(YEAR, '1900', DATEADD(d, -1, GETDATE()) - r.BirthDate)
```

we subtract 1 day from the current date as the other day is '1/1/1900', which adds one day to the interval.

Answer (score 0):

In Snowflake:

```
ROUND(DATEDIFF('month', "dateOfBirth", CURRENT_DATE())/12)
```

You have to do it by months as if you pick years it seems to round up.